# QComboBox dynamic list of items

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I have two `QTableWidget`s. Let's call them `Tab1` and `Tab2`. One column of `Tab1` contains `QComboBox`es where their items are rows from `Tab2`. When elements of `Tab2` are modified (added/removed/edited) I want all `QComboBoxes` to update.

**Tab1** concept

```
LineNo | Some Text   | Select       |
1      | QString     | QComboBox    |
2      | QString     | QComboBox    |
3      | QString     | QComboBox    |
       |     ...     |     ...      |         
n      | QString     | QComboBox    |
```

**Tab2** concept

```
LineNo | Some Text   |
1      | QString     |
2      | QString     |
3      | QString     |
       |     ...     |
n      | QString     |
```

Currently `QComboBoxe`s are filled like this:

```
QStringList s; // List filled with data from Tab2
QTableWidget *tw = (QTableWidget*) ui->Tabspace->currentWidget()->childAt(10, 10);
QComboBox *names = new QComboBox();
names->addItems(s);
tw->setItem(row, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
tw->setCellWidget(row, 0, names);
```

This code is being launched every time I add row to **Tab1**

Easiest way would be change each `QComboBox` whenever item content of **Tab2** changes. My question is:

Is there a better way to achieve that? Maybe some way to pass pointer to `addItems()` or modifying just one `QComboBox` and cloning it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [QComboBox::setModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#setModel) to share one model with all combo boxes. When changing anything in tab 2, simply modify the model, and the combo boxes will update automatically.
For your usecase, it seems like [QStringListModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlistmodel.html) is a good model, although you can of course use more complex ones if needed.